django, djoser, simple jwt, google auth, Token has wrong type
i have react-django app, i'm using djoser with simplejwt for auth, and seperate have google auth, problem is that when i first time auth with google is creating new account and returning access with refresh and user, but this tokens are not valid, after auth on client i getting navigate to home page and is autofetching data with access token on header, but i get https://i.sstatic.net/pFatvYfg.png
on react i have reauth from rtk query, i trying to get new access token, but i get response
{"detail":"Token has wrong type","code":"token_not_valid"}

but if i login after that is working fine, this problem i get only when first time create account with google and returning access with refresh tokens, and they are not valids
here is code my code
settings
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #installed apps below
    'usersAuth',
    'novel',
    'payment',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
    'djoser',
]


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend'],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
}


SIMPLE_JWT = {
   'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',),
   'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=30),
   'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
   'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
   'VERIFYING_KEY': None
}

DJOSER = {
    'LOGIN_FIELD': 'email',
    'PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'ACTIVATION_URL': 'activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL': True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_SHOW_EMAIL_NOT_FOUND': True,
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create': 'usersAuth.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user': 'usersAuth.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user_delete': 'djoser.serializers.UserDeleteSerializer',
        'activation': 'usersAuth.serializers.MyActivationSerializer',
    }
}

views
class LoginWithGoogle(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        if 'code' in request.data.keys():
            code = request.data['code']
            id_token = get_id_token(code)
            user_email = id_token['email']


            try: # if user already exist in database
                user = AppUser.objects.get(email=user_email)
                refresh = get_jwt_token(user)
                serializer = UserGoogleSerialzer(user)
                return Response({'refresh': str(refresh),
                                 'access': str(refresh.access_token),
                                 'user': serializer.data

            })
            except AppUser.DoesNotExist:
                return Response({
                        "id_token": id_token
                    }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        
        
        if ('id_token' in request.data.keys()) and ('username' in request.data.keys()):
            user = AppUser.objects.create_user(
                    username=request.data['username'],
                    email=request.data['id_token']['email'],
                    img_url=request.data['id_token']['picture'],
                    provider='google'
                )
            refresh = get_jwt_token(user)
            serializer = UserGoogleSerialzer(user)
            return Response({
                    'access': str(refresh),
                    'refresh': str(refresh.access_token),
                    'user': serializer.data
                        }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

utils
def get_jwt_token(user):
    token = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
    return token


def get_id_token(code):
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'

    # Exchange auth code for access token, refresh token, and ID token
    credentials = client.credentials_from_clientsecrets_and_code(
        CLIENT_SECRET_FILE,
        [
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
            'openid', 'email', 'profile'
        ],
        code
    )
    
    return credentials.id_token

